# Fill Masked Contour Intersected with Rect

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got a Mat image which is a binary mask that I segmented and a cv::Rect that identifies an specific region. When I get the contours of the binary mask the image is like this:

[Binary Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUbpg.png)

[Contours generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIuDq.png)

I would like to fill in the mask the region that intersects with the rectangle. How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good choice would be to use `cv::min()` with the binary image and another cv::Mat() with the area under `cv::Rect()` painted as white. It will filter out the desired portion under the Rect as:

```
// Create a grayscale canvas with black background
cv::Mat canvas = cv::Mat(binary_img.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

// I created a dummy rect replace it with original rect coordinates.
cv::Rect boundingRect = cv::Rect(100, 100, 200, 200);

// Draw filled rect onto the black canvas with white color
cv::rectangle(binary_image, boundingRect, cv::Scalar(255), -1);

// Take the min of binary image and canvas to filter out the contours
cv::min(binary_image, canvas, binary_image);
```

EDIT:

If you want to filter the contours which intersect the `cv::Rect`, then you need to iterate over each contour, calculate the boundingRect and check if it intersects the given rect.

```
for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
    if ((cv::boundingRect(contours[i]) & boundingRect).area() > 0) {
        // Your desired contours found.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, ZdaR. Thanks for your reply!! But, what I would like to do is fill the region (contour) that intersects with the rectangle. In some cases, the region is bigger than the rect and in some cases (like in the image) it is completely inside. So, I want to identify which contour intersects with the rectangle and fill this region in the binary image.

Answer (score 1):

There is way simpler than @ZdaR's solution: using Regions Of Interest (ROI) which directly selects the bounding rectangle region to process.

```
cv::Rect boundingRect(/* x, y, width, height */);
contours_image(boundingRect).setTo(255, binary_image(boundingRect));
```

Here, I select each region with operator parenthesis `contours_image(boundingRect)` and `binary_image(boundingRect)`, and use the binary image part as a mask to set all corresponding pixels to 255.

[image]